# Bind C-return to org-insert-item

Tags: org-mode

I want to bind C-return to org-insert-item

```
  (global-set-key (kbd "<C-return>") 'org-insert-item)
```

When restart emacs, it does not work

consult to `describe-key` it still return the default key sequence.

```
<C-return> runs the command cua-set-rectangle-mark (found in
cua-global-keymap), which is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function
in ‘cua-rect.el’.

It is bound to <C-return>.

[Arg list not available until function definition is loaded.]

Start rectangle at mouse click position.
```

What's the problem with my key binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are with `cua-mode` activated.

This global minor mode binds `<C-return>` to `cua-set-rectangle-mark`.

Probably you are activating it in your init file.